# Configuring routing table with 2 network interfaces

Tags: routing, ip-routing

I have a Linux server with two network interfaces: `eth0` (connected to internet using a public IP address `A.B.C.208`) and `eth1` (not connected to anything, bind to a private IP address `10.U.V.159`). The private network part is required because I configured a VPN (OpenSwan) whose configuration require it.

My OpenSwan VPN links my `10.U.V.*` private network to a remote `10.X.Y.*` private network. The VPN link is established and works fine.

But when I ping a server on the remote `10.X.Y.*` network, I need to force the source interface to `eth1` to make it work:

```
$ ping -I eth1 10.X.Y.31
PING 10.X.Y.31 (10.X.Y.31) from 10.U.V.159 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.X.Y.31: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=29.0 ms
...
```

Otherwise the OpenSwan/VPN won't reroute the ping.

**How can I configure my server to automatically set the source address to `eth1/10.U.V.159` when accessing any `10.X.Y.*` address?** Should I add a route? I do not want to interfere with the VPN own routing mechanism...

My routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         A.B.C.254       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.U.V.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
A.B.C.0         *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

10.X.Y.31 doesn't exists in your routing table. So the default route is used, and the packet is sent by eth0.
If you want to send it by eth1, you will need to have the next gateway, you could use the `route add -net 10.X.Y.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.U.V.159`command

It is maybe a problem of mask, the 10.0.0.0 network is usually in /8.

Comment: Thanks, indeed adding a route to `10.X.Y.*` to gateway "itself" solved the issue.

Comment: The command I used is `route add -net 10.X.Y.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.U.V.159`. Can you add this to your answer? That way I could mark it as an answer.